# Need a command/script that can generate output in a single line with all the needed info

Tags: linux, text-processing

How to generate an output below using bash script/or command:

Desired output:

```
contacts.USA | Name:John Due | Gender:Male | Age:21 | Address: Texas    
contacts.USA | Name:Ed Mundo | Gender:Male | Age:41 | Address: California    
contacts.BRAZIL | Name:Tom Paul | Gender:Male | Age:26 | Address: Sau Paulo
```

Example input:
I have 100 of contacts file for diff. countries.

**Contacts.USA**

```
Name:John Due 
Gender:Male 
Age:21
Address: Texas

Name:Ed Mundo 
Gender:Male 
Age:41 
Address: California
```

**Contacts.Brazil**

```
Name:Tom Paul
Gender:Male 
Age:26 
Address: Sau Paulo
```

I'm using unix cmd below but unable to generate the desired output.

```
grep -E 'Name|Gender|Age|Address' contacts.*
```

output of this cmd is showing the result in a row:

```
contacts.USA Name:John Due 
contacts.USA Gender:Male 
contacts.USA Age:21 
contacts.USA Address: Texas
contacts.USA Name:Ed Mundo 
contacts.USA Gender:Male     
contacts.USA Age:41    
contacts.USA Address: California    
contacts.BRAZIL Name:Tom Paul     
contacts.BRAZIL Gender:Male    
contacts.BRAZIL Age:26    
contacts.BRAZIL Address: Sau Paulo
```

Comment: Having seen how your first attempt did not do what you wanted, what else have you tried?

Comment: I strongly recommend using an actual database.  If you have such a huge number of contact files, it will be easier and more robust.

Comment: Linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389362/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

Assuming input files `contacts.USA` and `contacts.BRAZIL`.

```
awk '/Name/{ printf "%s | %s",FILENAME,$0 }
     /Gender|Age|Address/{ printf " | %s",$0; if($0~/Address/) print "" }' contacts.*
```

- `/Name/{ printf "%s | %s",FILENAME,$0 }` - capturing line with `Name` keyword, appending the filename `FILENAME` to the start of the resulting string
- `if($0~/Address/) print ""` - print record separator (newline) after encountering line with `Address` keyword

---

The output:

```
contacts.BRAZIL | Name:Tom Paul | Gender:Male  | Age:26  | Address: Sau Paulo
contacts.USA | Name:John Due  | Gender:Male  | Age:21 | Address: Texas
contacts.USA | Name:Ed Mundo  | Gender:Male  | Age:41  | Address: California
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat idiomatic awk version - using "paragraph mode":

```
$ awk '{$1=FILENAME OFS $1} 1' RS= FS='\n' OFS=' | ' Contacts.*
Contacts.Brazil | Name:Tom Paul | Gender:Male  | Age:26  | Address: Sau Paulo
Contacts.USA | Name:John Due  | Gender:Male  | Age:21 | Address: Texas
Contacts.USA | Name:Ed Mundo  | Gender:Male  | Age:41  | Address: California
```

A similar implementation in perl:

```
perl -Mfeature=say -F'\n' -00ne 'say join " | ", $ARGV, @F' Contacts.*
```